# What is the general process and timeline for providing latest gcc compiler versions in an LTS release?

Tags: 20.04, gcc

For example Ubuntu 20.04 provides gcc-10 packages but it is still missing gcc-11. Both Ubuntu 21.04 and 21.10 provide gcc-11 packages. When does 20.04 get gcc-11? I am aware there are other ways to install gcc-11, but I am interested in finding out it's general availability in 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Not really, 20.04 provides gcc-10 over and above gcc-9. Question is more about how and when compiler packages with higher version make into the 20.04 repositories. @mchid answer is helpful in that it may never get a release.

Comment: Upgrades occur when security fixes are required; in most cases that means security patches are back-ported to existing packages - but there are rare exceptions where it's more work to backport fixes than to provide & fully QA-test the newer version; in which case the newer version will replace the older package. That has occurred twice thus for with *focal* (or 20.04); but it's rare.  No-one has a crystal ball; but yeah it's unlikely security-flaws in gcc-9 will be that bad that it'll be replaced with gcc-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When does 20.04 get gcc-11?

Probably never. For example, 20.04 has `gcc-10` but 18.04 only has up to `gcc-8`.

In order to gain access to newer versions of gcc, [the generally accepted method](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain#Toolchain_Updates) is to use the [ubuntu-toolchain-r/test ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```